# Blazor LocalStorage not retrieving saved values

Tags: local-storage, blazor

I'm using .NET 5 Blazor Application... I have a class with 3 boolean attributes which I'm saving and retrieving from the LocalStorage and it works...the problem is when I restart the application and I get the values they are always false despite I inspected with the browser dev tools (Application tab) and I see some are true. What is wrong?

This is what I use:

To set the values

```
await Local.SetItemAsync("item-" + itemId, new ItemUiBehaviour()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

To read the values:

```
var itemUiBehaviour = await Local.GetItemAsync<ItemUiBehaviour>("item-" + itemId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Thx in advance. Guillermo

**UPDATE**

This is the UiBehaviour Class

```
namespace Company.Data
{
    public class ItemUiBehaviour
    {
        public bool Show { get; private set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; private set; }
        public bool AutoRefresh { get; private set; }

        public void ToggleShow()
        {
            Show = !Show;
        }

        public void SetShow(bool show)
        {
            Show = show;
        }

        public void SetEnabled(bool enabled)
        {
            Enabled = enabled;
        }

        public void SetAutoRefresh(bool autoRefresh)
        {
            AutoRefresh = autoRefresh;
        }

        public void ToggleEnable()
        {
            Enabled = !Enabled;
        }

        public void ToggleAutoRefresh()
        {
            AutoRefresh = !AutoRefresh;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `private` before `set;`

The deserializer cannot set the properties now.

```cs
//public bool Show { get; private set; }
  public bool Show { get; set; }
```

Comment: You're right! Can't believe I didn't see it...but what I don't like is to expose the property, isn't there a way I can keep the setter private but also specify the deserializer how to do it? (through the SetShow method)

Comment: You could write a Wrapper. But is that any better than SetShow() ?